# Style KML layers

Tags: kml

I have inserted KML layers in a google map but I notice that I would like to stylize the polygons.
I believe I change the style in the KML code itself before inserting in a google map? I have the following code for every polygon in the KML layer. How can I stylize is? I am not sure why it says LineStyle because it is in polygon. Is the fill the fill of the colour? Should I change that to a number other than 0?

```
<Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
```

Comment: Did you read the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference)? It explains all those tags.

Comment: It did not work. So I ended up symbolizing the layers in ArcMap and saving it as a KMZ in order to preserve the symbology

Answer (score 0):

It says linestyle because the outline of a polygon is a line. So you are essentially applying style to that line. You also want to use PolyStyle which is shading the inner polygon.

```
<Style id="pnt1"><LineStyle><color>6345C3DD</color><width>1.5</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>6345C3DD</color></PolyStyle></Style>
```